# Code after thread not being executed

Tags: java, android

I am working on extracting some html for an android app. A problem I have is that the code after the thread in the code below is not being executed. I feel like I'm making an amateur mistake but I don't see what it is. I know the arraylists are being populated, from printing the their contents into logcat in the createTimetable() method.
However anything after `}).start();` is not being done. Any ideas?

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_online_timetable);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    value = intent.getStringExtra("url");


      new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Log.d("url",value);
                    doc = Jsoup.connect(value).get();
                    Element monday = doc.select("p ~ table").first();
                    Element tuesday = doc.select("p ~ table").get(1);
                    Element wednesday = doc.select("p ~ table").get(2);
                    Element thursday = doc.select("p ~ table").get(3);
                    Element friday = doc.select("p ~ table").get(4);

                    monday.select("tr:eq(0)").remove();
                    tuesday.select("tr:eq(0)").remove();
                    wednesday.select("tr:eq(0)").remove();
                    thursday.select("tr:eq(0)").remove();
                    friday.select("tr:eq(0)").remove();


                    final Elements mon = monday.select("td");
                    final Elements tues = tuesday.select("td");
                    final Elements wed = wednesday.select("td");
                    final Elements thurs = thursday.select("td");
                    final Elements fri = friday.select("td");               

                    Log.d("thread","sdsddssd");
                    createTimetable(monClasses, mon, day1);
                    createTimetable(tuesClasses, tues, day2);
                    createTimetable(wedClasses, wed, day3);
                    createTimetable(thurClasses, thurs, day4);
                    createTimetable(friClasses, fri, day5);


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
          }).start();


      Log.d("sdfsdfsdf", "HELLO");
      for(int i = 0; i<monClasses.size();i++)
      {
          Log.d("monday", monClasses.get(i).toString());
      }


    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());

}
```

[image: logcat]

Comment: Can you post the output of logcat?

Comment: You should try to reduce the code you post to the minimal fragment that will reproduce your problem. This has clearly nothing to do with the days of the week, all that makes the question unpleasant to read through

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you come from traditional java development so here's a word of warning: Threads and Android do not like each other. Switch your thread to an [Async Task](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and try again, it's only a few lines of code to change.

Basically, copy all your code to the `doInBackground()` method and then call `task.execute()`.
Everything you want to do with the data that was generated should go into the `onPostExecute()` method of the Async task. You can even do parallel processing by using `publishResult()` and `onResultPublished()`
Note that this might run synchronous but you should not have to worry about that.

Comment: Ok, I will try out this asynctask. It looks a bit messy but I'll figure it out.

Comment: async tasks are the way to go on android, i would not call them messy

Answer (score 1):

Since you aren't doing any UI work after the thread can you not do the work in a finally clause?

If you are relying on this thread to gather data to fill views you should use AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

try to assign thread to a variable and start that thread variable at end of onCreate method